# Series solution around $x=0$ of $x\frac{dy}{dx}=y(1+x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Consider the first order equation
$$x\frac{dy}{dx}=y(1+x).$$
The point $x=0$ is a singular point, so my understanding is that it is not possible to find a power series solution of the form
$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\,x^n.$$
However, I found
$$y(x)=c\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n-1)!},$$
which agrees with the usual solution $y(x)=x\,e^x$.

What is going on here? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is incorrect.
As this example shows, a differential equation **might** have power series solutions around a singular point.